# Gates Carbon Drive off-road experience?

Tags: off-road, belt-drive

I am planning on a new bicycle and one idea is a Fat bike with the corresponding Rohloff and a Gates carbon drive. I am using Rohloff's for more than 10 years and know what to expect. I am absolutely new to Gates carbon drive and I am unsure, whether these can be recommended on MTBs or for off-road usage. I've heard that dirt is a problem. However, the problem, according to corrsponding stories, is chiefly acoustics, i.e. sequaky noise. I've never heard that the drive would break or not perform as intended.

Do the pros of a carbon drive system still outweigh it's number of drawbacks, even when when the latter is increased due to off-road usage?

Comment: Do you know of a fat bike frame that will take a gates?

Comment: Just for fun I Googled for fat bikes with gates carbon and there are a few, but they mostly seem to be custom bikes. However once you've gone to the point of using a Rohloff hub and a carbon drive, custom frame modifications probably would be out of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem I see with Gates Carbon Drive on a fat bike is that you have to have a frame that "breaks" in the rear triangle to accommodate threading the belt. Have you checked to make sure there's a frame available that supports fat bike tires and also supports breaking the chainstays. As far as off-roading goes, that would create a potential weak spot in the frame. Although I"m sure any quality bike manufacturer would account for that when building such a frame.

Comment: This is exactly the bottom line of the answers I've got from several bike dealers, i.e. the necessary frame modification to use the Gates Drive weakens frame stability beyond a degree, where hard MTBiking is feasible from a mechanical stability point of view - even if some bike / frame manufacturers sell those.

Comment: I would think the only way to really do it properly would be to have a frame builder build the frame around the belt. I'm not a frame builder so I couldn't say if one couldn't rebuild the frame every time the belt needed to be changed, which hopefully wouldn't be that often. Another option would be to use a [frame design such as this](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/now-that-was-a-bike-alpinestars-ti-mega-2014.html) so that the belt doesn't have to go through the frame. I can't speak to how strong it was.  The article does mention some strength problems around the bottom bracket.

Comment: There is a German manufacturer Maxx who sells a customisable hardtail, which allows for a gates drive. See [here](http://www.fat-bike.de/maxx-fatbikes/). It is called Jagamoasta, which is Bavarian dialect for hunting master.
I've decided against such experiments and bought the [Dude](https://www.canyon.com/mtb/dude/dude-cf-9-0.html), also German manufacturer, which was not my focus at all ;-).